# Can you use the Facebook API to update a Page (rather than a Profile)?

Tags: php, api, facebook

As far as I can tell you can't add the Developer package to a Pages account - as in I haven't got a Facebook profile.
It's for business purposes and I'd really like to know if you can use the Facebook API to update a Pages status.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible although not officially documented.

Pageids behave in many function calls very similar to profileids.

You dont need to add the developer app to a page - remember: you neither need your users to add it.

I am pretty sure that the Stream API wont work. But you can do the approach described at http://www.allfacebook.com/2009/04/public-profile-twitter/

If you are not into Development and simply want to update your page you can use your twitter account and add a hashtag to sync it to your facebook page with Selective Twitter.
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=115463795461

Update: as pointed out below http://ping.fm is also a good service offering this feature

Comment: Thank you Andreas - I've found a slightly different method using Ping.fm.
This seems a really good setup as I can now add Twitter, Facebook and all the others and then use Ping.fm's API calls to update all of them at once.

I'm glad it's not officially documented - makes me feel less stupid!

I'll look at integrating correctly with all of them at some point as I don't want to be reliant on third party services.